# Node js selenium multiple loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have written a script in node with selenium webdriver for automation testing. Below in the script

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until,
    _und = require('underscore');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.????.com/');
driver.wait(function() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='container']/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/a[1]")).then(function(link) {
        link.click();
    });
    driver.findElements(By.css("div.pu-final > span.fk-bold")).then(function(priceSpans) {
        console.log(priceSpans.length)
        _und.each(priceSpans, function(span) {
            span.getText().then(
                function(price) {
                    console.log(price)
                }
            );
        });
    });
    }, 20000);
driver.quit();
```

But it prints the output multiple time in console.

```
32
Rs. 5,499
Rs. 13,499
Rs. 10,999
Rs. 15,990
Rs. 8,499
Rs. 11,998
Rs. 6,999
Rs. 12,990
Rs. 7,999
Rs. 9,199
Rs. 9,990
Rs. 15,499
Rs. 9,999
Rs. 17,499
Rs. 9,999
Rs. 8,999
Rs. 8,990
Rs. 21,499
Rs. 38,499
Rs. 11,390
Rs. 10,999
Rs. 14,249
Rs. 8,999
Rs. 6,999
Rs. 6,999
Rs. 12,499
Rs. 22,999
Rs. 10,999
Rs. 18,499
Rs. 27,900
Rs. 27,900
Rs. 16,999
32
Rs. 5,499
Rs. 13,499
Rs. 10,999
Rs. 15,990
Rs. 8,499
Rs. 11,998
Rs. 6,999
Rs. 12,990
Rs. 7,999
Rs. 9,199
Rs. 9,990
Rs. 15,499
Rs. 9,999
Rs. 17,499
Rs. 9,999
Rs. 8,999
Rs. 8,990
Rs. 21,499
Rs. 38,499
Rs. 11,390
Rs. 10,999
Rs. 14,249
Rs. 8,999
Rs. 6,999
Rs. 6,999
Rs. 12,499
Rs. 22,999
Rs. 10,999
Rs. 18,499
Rs. 27,900
Rs. 27,900
Rs. 16,999
```

Comment: driver.findElements(By.css("div.pu-final > span.fk-bold")).then(function(priceSpans), can you please remove this "s" from driver.findElement(s), what happens?

Comment: I got  NoSuchElementError: no such element after removing s

Comment: it should have happened, you should at least find one. Has your HTML page changed?

Answer (score 0):

first of all u should understand how promises work. Every driver method returns a promise(future action). Chaining them helps you to perform actions sequentially:

```
driver.get(url).then(function(){
  //this will be called when the webpage is loaded, i.e document ready, from
    here you should locate the element you want to click
   return driver.findElement(By.xpath....);
}).then(function(link){
    //i have not worked with web elements but i believe it should also return promise
    return link.click(); // after you click if there is some ajax response 
      //in the next function you should wait for it to appear
}).then(function(){
   return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(''));
}).then(function(){
})
```

hope this helps.